# Sorting Slickgrid by Multiple Columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, slickgrid

I just started testing out [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki) for a project I'm working on and I'm very impressed with its performance. One requirement I have is sorting on multiple columns. I don't fully have my head wrapped around the Dataview in Slickgrid, so maybe I'm missing something obvious, but is there a way to sort a grid on multiple columns? Even if the UI can't handle sorting by more than one, I would like to be able to call a function with the columns in order, plus ascending or descending. I was able to do this with [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html), but it doesn't have grouping (another requirement for the project).

In the worst case, I will resort to doing the sorting on the server and serving the content back to the client statically sorted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can chain sort comparers to do multiple column sorting.  Instead of doing

```
function comparerOnCol1(a, b) {
  return a["col1"] - b["col1"];
}

function comparerOnCol2(a, b) {
  return a["col2"] - b["col2"];
}
```

you can do

```
// sort by col1, then col2
function combinedComparer(a, b) {
  return comparerOnCol1(a, b) || comparerOnCol2(a, b);  // etc.
}
```

or just implement it inline.

As far as reflecting the sort order in the UI, while you can't do directly, you can apply the sort indicators by setting "headerCssClass" on the column definitions you're sorting by and having them display the arrows (or however else you're indicating sort columns).

Comment: Thanks @tin. This seems to be what I need. But can I sort with just the grid, or do I need to make use of DataView if I want to implement sorting/filtering? I have it displaying with just the grid, but implementing DataView seems like it will involve a lot more work on my part.

Comment: The grid does not manipulate your data.  You do.
That being said, you don't have to use DataView to sort.
Just sort your data and invalidate the grid to reflect the changes in the data.  
As in: myData.sort(combinedComparer)

Comment: I'm wrestling with the same question at the moment.  I need multi-column sorting and filtering, but I haven't implemented DataView.  DataView seems to do only single-column sorting, but probably there is a way to override that.

Comment: @Fantius - You don't need to use DataView for sorting.  Just sort your data directly and invalidate the grid using grid.invalidate().

Answer (score 8):

I got it working for dataView with multi-column sort in the way. Was the easiest one to understand too. This is from the example in github, except that I've to pass one more parameter for dataView.sort(). It can always be true, and you can take care of the sort direction in your function.

```
grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    gridSorter(args.sortCols, dataView);
});

function gridSorter(sortCols, dataview) {
    dataview.sort(function (row1, row2) {
        for (var i = 0, l = sortCols.length; i < l; i++) {
            var field = sortCols[i].sortCol.field;
            var sign = sortCols[i].sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
            var x = row1[field], y = row2[field];
            var result = (x < y ? -1 : (x > y ? 1 : 0)) * sign;
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }, true);
}
```

Just in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

There's an example here that uses the 'multiColumnSort' option.

http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-multi-column-sort.html

I don't think it works though, because args.sortCols is always an array of 1.

[Edit]
In order for it work, I need to hold shift before clicking on a column header (not very intuitive IMHO)
See also: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/pull/276

Answer (score 1):

I spent a while trying to solve this with dataview (without shift key shenanigans) and I think I found the way to do it.

Use single column sort `{multiColumnSort: false}` and store the sort arguments in a closure. Defer to the previous comparitor if fields are equal.

```
var currentSortCmp = null;  
grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {

    // declarations for closure
    var field = args.sortCol.field;
    var sign = args.sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
    var prevSortCmp = currentSortCmp;

    // store closure in global
    currentSortCmp = function (dataRow1, dataRow2) {

        var value1 = dataRow1[field], value2 = dataRow2[field];

        //if equal then sort in previous closure (recurs)
        if (value1 == value2 && prevSortCmp)
            return prevSortCmp(dataRow1, dataRow2);

        return (value1 == value2 ? 0 : (value1 > value2 ? 1 : -1)) * sign;
    };
    dataView.sort(currentSortCmp);

    grid.invalidate();
    grid.render();      
});
```

remembers all previous orders. just works. works as expected.